# How to dynamically change DIR_APPLICATION in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3, opencart-3

Is there any way to change `DIR_APPLICATION` or change `catalog` to any other directory name dynamically using vqmod or any other configuration ?

Comment: why do you need so? you can override with vqmod but statically only

Comment: I know that but need any other way to change it

Comment: it's a constant, once declared it cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

You would *think* you can change the name of the catalog directory by modifying `config.php` and `admin/config.php` - but you'd be wrong!

This value is hardcoded in a number of places in OpenCart - look for `$this->load->model` calls - and you are also at risk of a mod hardcoding it as well.  It's best to leave the name at "catalog".

Comment: it is strange why this is needed at all, it better to add another const if needed, or even do this htaccess, server settings etc if so needed for url redirection.